# How to remove index.php from url using .htaccess this for me not working

Tags: .htaccess, short, phpfox

Hello i have this problem i try to short url for my phpfox site v4 version but this .htaccess not working for me

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(file)/(.*) PF.Base/$1/$2

RewriteRule ^static/ajax.php index.php
RewriteRule ^themes/default/(.*) PF.Base/theme/default/$1
RewriteRule ^(static|theme|module)/(.*) PF.Base/$1/$2
RewriteRule ^(Apps|themes)/(.*) PF.Site/$1/$2


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php/$1
```

Which is another way to be able to try, mod_rewrite is enabled but stil not working

Comment: How is it "not working"? Any error?.

Comment: http://s4.postimg.org/96px7v1xo/new.jpg

Comment: When change $_CONF['core.url_rewrite'] = '2'; in $_CONF['core.url_rewrite'] = '1'; with this  .htaccess  It looks like the picture above

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you have **mod_rewrite** enable on your `apache` server.
2. Go to `yoursite.com/index.php/admincp/setting/url/` and copy the `.htaccess` code
3. Create a file `.htaccess` with that code in root of your project.
4. Click on **Enable short urls** button in `yoursite.com/index.php/admincp/setting/url/` or just edit `PF.Base\file\settings\server.sett.php`, find `$_CONF['core.url_rewrite'] = '2';` and change it to `$_CONF['core.url_rewrite'] = '1';`
5. Now you open `yoursite.com/admincp/setting/url/` to make sure that short url is working

> Don't forgot to clear your browser cache once this process is done.

Thanks